# Element remover for Firefox without context menus

Tags: html, firefox

["Nuke Everything Advanced"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nuke-anything-enhanced) works well, but it's inconvenient to open content menu for each element to be removed. I want to "shoot down" multiple elements without just one click per removal.

Are there alternatives for this extension?

Comment: There's [Aardvark](http://superuser.com/a/146254/27264), bit it's not available for newer firefoxes.

Comment: Built-in: Shift-Ctrl-I (Inspector), click the pointer, select the element, press "del" to remove it?

Comment: @Izzy, Is it faster than open context menu and select "Remove this object" entry? I want to save clicks and remove multiple elements quickly.

Comment: "for each element"? Certainly. For one element only: probably not, but not slower either :) Have you tried?

Comment: @Izzy, Now I found (the deletion mode does not activate until I click on the source pane). Now the missing feature is the undo.

Comment: Ctrl-R (Reload the page) – there is no undo. Neither did you specify its need with your question :)

Comment: @Vi. What is your icon from?

Answer (score 1):

As [Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy) commented, Firefox's out-of-the-box features can be used for this.

Here is a screencast how to do it:

1. Open a page where you have element to be deleted:

[image: 1]

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>:

[image: 2]

3. Press "Pick element from the page" button:

[image: 3]

4. Click on some element in the source pane:

[image: 4]

5. Hover the mouse over the element to be removed **without clicking**:

[image: 5]

6. Press <kbd>Del</kbd>;
7. Hower the next element, press <kbd>Del</kbd> again and so on.

Disadvantage: no undo. After N correct deletion with N+1'th invalid deletion, you need to reload the page and redo all N ones...